# Regex: need to validate input for single, multiple or a range of postcodes

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a (four digits) postcode field that can accept:

1. A single postcode (e.g. 4009) -> it has to be four digit
2. Multiple postcodes separated by comma(s) (e.g. 4002,5001)
3. A range of postcodes using hyphen (e.g. 4000-4010)
4. Any combination of #1 and #3 separated by comma(s) (e.g. 4000,4002,4005-4010,5001)

Another example of #4 will be: 4000-4007,5000

How can I do validation using regex in C#. My question is more about how to construct the pattern itself. Thank you.

**Updates**

This is what I came up with (using your inputs on regex):

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var stringValue = value.ToString().Replace(" ", "");

    foreach (var pc in stringValue.Split(','))
    {
        if(!Regex.Match(pc, @"^(\d{4})$|^(\d{4}-\d{4})$").Success)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I was kind of hoping to do the validation without having to do string.Split(). I am not sure if that's possible at all. If anyone has better idea, please post it here. Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if regex can detect this as well. Ideally it should not take 4009-4000, i.e. in the range, the first number should be lower than or equal to the second number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `^((\d{4})([,-])?)+$`

Edit: That one matched on 80789809 aswell

New: `^(\d{4})(([,-])(\d{4}))*$`

Tested against:

```
4000,4002,4005-4010,5001 yes
4000-4007,5000 yes
4000-4010 yes
4002,5001 yes
4009 yes
40004002,4005-1010,5001 no
4000-4007, 5000 no
40004010 no
4002,50012345 no
4009, no
```

Comment: Excellent. I have tested it myself and it seems to cover all possibilities. Thanks Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is

```
^\d{4}(-\d{4})?(,\d{4}(-\d{4})?)*$
```

This is one or more ranges separated by commas, where each range is either a single postal code or a postal code dash postal code.

If you want efficiency, you will want to make non-capturing groups, as in

```
^\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?(,\d{4}(?:-\d{4})?)*$
```

Comment: I don't want to capture anything ... I just need to validate that the string follows that pattern. Using your regex, I tried to run "4000,500d5" and it still returns true.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited the answer to add the `^` and `$` anchors.  Let me know if you need a fuller example.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, and allow for optional whitespace between the various components:

```
^\s*(\d{4}(\s*-\s*\d{4}))(\s*,\s*(\d{4}(\s*-\s*\d{4})))*\s*$
```

Comment: I am not sure how to put codes in this comment box ... but anyway, I tried the following:

Match match = Regex.Match(stringValue, @"^\s*(\d{4}(\s*-\s*\d{4}))(\s*,\s*(\d{4}(\s*-\s*\d{4})))*\s*$");

and it returns false for "4000,4005"