# Single regex for folder path validation (Remote Path,FTP Path,Local System Folder Path,etc.,) in c#

Tags: c#, regex, path, directory

I want single Regex for folder Path Validation (Remote Path,FTP Path,Local System Folder Path,etc.,) in C#.

Example:

1. `c:\folder one\folder2\folder 3`
2. `\\remoteMachine\folder1`
3. `\\1.22.33.444\folder 1\folder2`
4. `ftp://12.123.112.231/`
5. `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: need to validate input for single, multiple or a range of postcodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341719/regex-need-to-validate-input-for-single-multiple-or-a-range-of-postcodes)

Comment: _"folder path validation"_ - why? Simply try to access the path specified. A valid string can still point to a resource that doesn't exist or isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] inputs = {
                  @"c:\folder one\folder2\folder 3",
                  @"\\remoteMachine\folder1",
                  @"\\1.22.33.444\folder 1\folder2",
                  @"ftp://12.123.112.231/",
                  @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome"
                             };
            string ip = @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}";
            string pattern = string.Format( @"^[A-Z]:(\\(\w+\s*)+)+" + // filename
                             @"|^\\\\{0}(\\(\w+\s*)+)+" +              // url with ip
                             @"|^\\(\\(\w+\s*)+)+" +                   // network filename \\abc\def
                             @"|^FTP://{0}/" +                         // ftp with ip
                             @"|^FTP://[A-Z]\w+/", ip);                // ftp with hostname


            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                bool match = Regex.IsMatch(input,pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" {1}", input, match? "matches" : "does not match");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Try explaining your answer...

Comment: What needs explaining?  For anybody who understands basic Regex it is obvious.  Most postings on Regex the person knows Regex but can't figure out exact syntax.

Comment: _"What needs explaining?"_ - the thoughts behind the regular expressions you made up, so someone can verify they implement those principles correctly, and improve them if they later find this post. For example support for an FTP URI with a hostname instead of an IP. Please read [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain/298811#298811) my stance on "try this" answers. You don't have to agree, I'm just trying to explain that I think dumping code without explanation may not be as useful for others as you think.

Comment: Added comments and included FTP with hostname.

Comment: jdweng Thanks Working Fine ....

Comment: Then why did somebody give me -2 points?